# How to ues javac to compile .java files wrote in a txt file?

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I have some .java file, like a.java, b.java, c.java...., is there a way to compile them together by writting .java files' name into a txt file, and use some javac opitions to compile them?  Like "javac (some options here) a.txt".  The txt file contains the name of .java file that I want to compile.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write java files paths separated by whitespace or newline to **file.txt** and call **javac** prepending **file.txt** with **@**

```
javac @file.txt
```